# @Entry with no hard-coded base

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have to create an Ldap User class and therefore an @Entry annotation has to be specified. I don't want the base to be hard-coded, is there any way to get it from application.properties and refer to it in the @Entry syntax?

```
@Entry(objectClasses = {"inetOrgPerson", "organizationalPerson", "person", "top" }, base = "ou=people")
public class LdapUser {
    @Id
    private Name dn; 
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```